# I set firefox proxy to use SSH Socks remote server but my public ip address on google doesn't change

Tags: linux, ssh

I used the command:

```
ssh -D 9090 username@ipv4 address
```

when I configure the settings to use socks on localhost 9090 for firefox in the proxy settings my ip address that I search up on google doesn't change like it's supposed to do.

I didn't use a VM and it's on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su].

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your client machine where you open the Firefox browser is machine A
And the remote server used as SOCKS proxy is machine B
So you run this command in B:

```
 ssh -g -D 9090 user@localhost
```

Where user: is a user on the SOCKS proxy machine or root 
As you see you need to add (-g) to allow remote hosts (like the client machine A) to connect to local forwarded ports (9090)

In your Firefox browser you go to:
Options -> Network Settings and click on "Settings" button and choose "Manual Proxy Configurations"
In the "Socks Host" put the public IP address of the Socks server (machine B) and in the Port put 9090
Click OK

Also make sure no firewall rules between the 2 machines that block outbound connection from the client machine A to port 9090 on the SOCKS machine B

Now it is good to clear your Firefox cache from 
Options -> Privacy & Security 
Under "Cookies and Site Data" click on "Clear Data" button

Now to verify that the public IP address you are facing the Internet with is the remote server (socks proxy) IP open this site:
https://whatismyipaddress.com/

It should gives you the IP address of the SOCKS server (machine B)